# Use RazorEngine IsolatedTemplateService with resolver?

Tags: razorengine

I'm using RazorEngine in a large web application to send email messages.  Because of memory concerns (from constantly recompiling templates for messages with ad-hoc content), I want to use `IsolatedTemplateService`, which runs in a separate AppDomain.  But I don't see any way to specify a template resolver, like I can with `TemplateService`.

Am I missing something?  I like my resolver.